# Pagination in apache cassandra

Tags: cassandra, pagination, cassandra-3.0

How is the pagination achieved in Cassandra, I understand by sending the last received **timestamp** we will be able to achieve it. Apart from that is there any other way to achieve the Pagination in Cassandra?

Also, Using timestamp has the limitation that it will help us paginate only in the insert order.

Comment: You mean pagination for data representation (on page, for example), or pagination as implementation detail of driver when working with big result sets?

Comment: For the web application data grid pagination use case like select * from user from 10 to 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a notion of page state that you can pass when executing query, and query will return results starting with "known state".  NodeJS driver exposes as `pageState` property of the result returned after execution of query - you can store this state in user's session (or web page itself), and reuse for next request, by putting it into options, something like (stolen from documentation):

```
const options = { pageState : pageState, prepare : true, fetchSize :  200 };
client.eachRow(query, parameters, options, function (n, row) { // Row callback.
 }, function (err, result) {       // End callback.
    // Store the next paging state.
    pageState = result.pageState;
 }
);
```

[NodeJS driver documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/3.3/features/paging/#manual-paging) provides more examples how to use it. You can also consult documentation for [Java driver](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/manual/paging/#saving-and-reusing-the-paging-state) - I believe that it have more details about page state.

There are also some caveats, like, you can't jump to arbitrary page, state may not be "compatible" between Cassandra versions (if you do rolling upgrade), etc.

Comment: This works like a fly, Thanks. I stored the previous and current pagestate and worked as expected. Agreed It will not make you jump. Do you think it has any issue / performance hiccups in using this each row and pagestate?

Comment: Shouldn't be - it's "standard" use case and should be optimized. But please read Java docs - they have more details on how to use it correctly

Answer (score -2):

```
$statement = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement("select * from tablename where id = ".$id); 
$result = $connection->execute($statement, new Cassandra\ExecutionOptions(array('page_size' => 5000)));

$result = $connection->execute($statement); 

while ($result) 
{ 
    foreach ($result as $row) 
    {
    } 
    if ($result->isLastPage()) 
    { 
        $page_size=$page_size+1; break; 
    }  
    $result = $result->nextPage(); 
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about PagingState (Fetch_Size) ? I am expecting the Pagination use case in Cassandra